# Add space before a numbers in PHP

Tags: php, string-formatting, padding

How can I add space before numbers in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), to get output like the following?

```
   9      
  10
 100
```

I'm using `str_pad($k,3,'',STR_PAD_LEFT)`, but blank space is not working. And I don't want leading zeros, but I want blank spaces.

Comment: Could you add some more detail about what exactly you are trying to achieve and an example?

Comment: #  9
# 10
#100

print like this

Comment: You have no space in your str_pad.

Answer (score 6):

You may be looking for [`str_pad()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php).

```
foreach (array(1,2,3,100,1000) as $number)
 echo str_pad($number, 10, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

However, if you want to output this in HTML, the multiple spaces will be converted to one. In that case, use `&nbsp;` as the third parameter.

Also, if you use a font like Times or Arial, this will never produce perfectly exact results, because characters differ in width. For perfect results, you need to use a Monospace font like `Courier`.

Anyway, check @Mark Baker's answer first. Right aligning the data using CSS's `text-align: right` is the best solution in most cases.

Comment: meh. @Mark Baker gave the right answer: do it in CSS. At least you didn't advise the use of `printf` and family though.

Comment: but i m getting #&n1 #&n2 with &nbsp;

Comment: @anu I'm sorry, `str_pad` doesn't work that way. Use normal spaces, and replace them afterwards: `$string = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $string`;

Answer (score 5):

If you're displaying the result in a web browser, then you should be aware that browsers have this nasty little tendency to convert multiple white spaces to a single space. To check if your code is working, use the browser's "view source" option and count the spaces in the actual source rather than the rendered display.

Then look at alternatives such as `&nbsp;` or right-aligning your values using [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).

Comment: +1 for css mention. This is a presentational issue, not a PHP issue. CSS is the correct and __easy__ way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

When printing the numbers:

```
printf("%5d\n", $number);
```

Replace the `5` with how many spaces width minimum you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
str_replace(" ","&nbsp;",str_pad($number, 5,'   ', STR_PAD_LEFT));
```

grml, look into my comment. I don't know why here the **nbsp** :) is gone

Comment: str_replace(" ","&nbsp;",str_pad($number, 5 ,' ', STR_PAD_LEFT))